# Convert UTF-8 Simplified Chinese UTF-8 Traditional Chinese characters in PHP

Tags: php, unicode, localization, cjk

On a UTF-8 PHP page, users may enter Traditional or Simplified Chinese characters, how can I convert all input Chinese characters to Traditional Chinese charters (UTF-8) in PHP?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998607/conversion-from-simplified-to-traditional-chinese