# Using iconv to convert Traditional Chinese to Simplified Chinese

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, iconv

How do I use the iconv in Ruby to convert a string from Simplified Chinese to Traditional Chinese (and vice-versa)?

I've tried

```
Iconv.conv("gb2312//IGNORE", "big5//IGNORE", '大家一起學中文')
```

I get an entirely different string. I've tried with the GBK and BIG5 encodings, I get an IllegalSequence Error.

Thanks.

Comment: Which ruby version do you use? Ruby 1.9 include encoding handling. You may use `String#encode('Big5')` to convert to Big5. I can't test it - I get only little squares when I run a testprogramm :(  (Seems chinese fonts are missing on my PC)

Comment: I tried it out, it doesn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 4):

https://rubygems.org/gems/tradsim

I just wrote a gem

To install the gem

```
gem install tradsim
```

To use the gem

```
# encoding: UTF-8
require 'tradsim'
puts Tradsim::to_sim("大家一起學中文")
```

it will yield

```
大家一起学中文
```

and you can use `Tradsim::to_trad` to do the reverse.

Comment: ur gem is inaccurate from my test

Comment: Can you give me an example so that I know whether it's because of programming error or the imperfection in the translation table? The translation table is imperfect. For example, for the character 后, I don't actually know if it's traditional chinese (as in 皇后) or its simplified chinese (as in 后來). I hope that someone can suggest a good way to deal with those characters which are the same in sim chinese but different in trad chinese.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to convert, say, 學 to 学? I could be wrong, but I don't think Iconv will perform that type of conversion.

Comment: yes, that's what I'm trying to do. Isn't it a simple Big5 to GB conversion? If iconv can't do that, do you know how I can do that with Ruby?

Comment: any idea how? i tried `@text = "大家一起學中文"
    
    @c = Iconv.conv('gb2312', 'utf-8', @text)
   @c = Iconv.conv('big5', 'gb2312', @c)
   @c = Iconv.conv('utf-8', 'big5', @c)`, does not work (gives me a different string)

Comment: ...but I think not. All Iconv should do, if I understand correctly, is spit out the exact same thing in a different encoding. Check out http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/5b78/index.htm and notice that 學 exists in both Big5 and GB.  学, however, only exists in GB. Hmm again. I think higher-level routines are needed to perform the transformation, since this isn't just an encoding difference, but I'm not certain.

Comment: There's some good discussion of the issues at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998607/conversion-from-simplified-to-traditional-chinese ; from that page, I was able to find http://mediawiki-zhconverter.googlecode.com/svn-history/r3/trunk/mediawiki-zhconverter.inc.php . It's PHP, but it should give you some idea of an algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

**OpenCC**

https://github.com/BYVoid/OpenCC

As of 2021, this sees to be the most popular choice:

```
sudo apt install opencc
opencc -i input.txt -o output.txt -c t2s.json
```

With:

input.txt

```
大家一起學中文
```

we get:

output.txt

```
大家一起学中文
```

It also has APIs for several languages like Python and Node.js.

Tested on Ubuntu 21.04, opencc 1.1.1.