# Convert Chinese simplified to traditional programmatically in C#

Tags: c#, unicode

Is there a reliable way to convert a given set of Simplified Chinese characters into their equivalent Traditional Chinese chars in a C# program?

Edit: If you use google translate, it's pretty reliable conversion from one to the other, however, how to do the conversion in C#?

Comment: closed because "It's difficult to tell what is being asked here"?? I mean, really??
The answer, of course, is that there is no reliable way; but have a look at the answers of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998607/conversion-from-simplified-to-traditional-chinese

Comment: I think this a decent question, why has everyone closed it?

Comment: I've lived in Asia and Taipei for years.  I've learnt some Mandarin (Traditional) and can sometimes figure out Shanghai (Simplified).  So did Beijing come up with a mapping algorithm when simplified was invented?

Comment: If you use google translate, it's pretty reliable conversion from one to the other, basically what I'm asking is how to do it in C#?

Answer (score 3):

Use UNIHAN database: http://www.unicode.org/charts/unihan.html

It is said: The Unihan Database organizes information relating to the properties of CJK Unified Ideographs. Unihan Database Documentation is available in UAX #38.