# Can I use only zh-Hans/zh-Hant resx files for Chinese if I don't need to support locale-specific variations?

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, internationalization, resx

**Background**
We have an older webforms application, and we're not using any custom language/globalization code that I'm aware of. We're using resx files for culture specific resources. For Chinese, we currently have **4** resx files: zh, zh-cn, zh-hans, and zh-hant. I am hoping to pair down to just **2** for simplicity's sake: zh-hans and zh-hant. We don't intend to support any locale-specific variations; just generic Simplified Chinese and generic Traditional Chinese.

**Question(s)**

1. My main question is this: **Are there any situations where I would *need* to have more than zh-hans or zh-hant files for Chinese?** *Outside of a need to support any locale-specific variations.
   Basically, I need to guarantee that if a user browses to our site using **zh**, **zh-cn**, **zh-sg** language codes, they will get resources from the **zh-hans** file, and if they browse using **zh-tw**, **zh-hk**, or **zh-mo**, they get resources from the **zh-hant** file. These are the only Chinese codes I know of, but if there are others, they should be included here as well - basically a Chinese speaking user with their browser set to any Chinese language, should see the appropriate Simplified or Traditional Chinese - and definitely never see English.
   So far my testing seems to indicate that yes, .NET resolves them correctly, but I want to be sure there are no hidden or rare scenarios I am missing.
2. I am aware that the zh-hans and zh-hant codes are a little newer - and are considered "parent" cultures. I am also aware that the old generic, parent codes were zh-chs and zh-cht. **Are there old browsers out there that allow these zh-chs/zh-cht codes to be selected, and if so, will .NET still resolve them appropriately?**
3. I am not entirely sure *how* .NET resolves the correct resource files, so if someone could point me in the right direction, such as **what classes/namespaces are involved**, that would also be great.

**Resources**
[Language codes for simplified Chinese and traditional Chinese?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892372/language-codes-for-simplified-chinese-and-traditional-chinese?rq=1) 
[IETF Language Tags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IETF_language_tag#ISO_3166-1_and_UN_M.49)

Answer (score 4):

The answer was no - you *can't* have only zh-hans/zh-hant. Because, if you do, and you pass the base **zh** code with your browser, it will NOT automatically resolve to the zh-hans or zh-hant resx files.

The reason is due to something called the “[Resource Fallback Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sb6a8618(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1)”.

Basically, .NET resolves resources through a hierarchy. It will start with the culture code requested, and if a resx for that specific culture code doesn’t exist, it will then begin to travel up the hierarchy, searching for the next culture code that *does* have a resx. But, it never travels down, only up.

Here is an example of the hierarchy for zh-sg [Singapore]:

1. Invariant
2. zh
3. zh-Hans
4. zh-chs (legacy generic code)
5. zh-sg (locale-specific codes)

So first it looks for zh-sg. If there is no resource file for zh-sg, it looks for zh-chs. If there is no resource file for zh-chs, it looks for zh-Hans. And so forth.

Having just zh-Hans and zh-Hant would work for all the locale-specific codes, such as zh-sg, zh-tw, etc. Some browsers allow you to select Generic Simplified (zh-Hans) or Generic Traditional (zh-Hant), and obviously it'd work in those scenarios as well. The only scenario it *wouldn't* work for is when base Chinese zh was selected and passed in the request. In that scenario, if zh doesn't exist, the next place it looks is the Invariant culture - in this case, that returns English text - which is obviously not what we want.

My solution, then, was to pair down to having base **zh**, and **zh-Hant** for my 2 codes. Base zh then is my file containing Simplified text, and zh-Hant of course is my file containing Traditional text. I could've done it the other way around (made zh contain Traditional text and used zh-Hans for Simplified) but really, there are no guidelines out there I can find, about what the base zh should represent. Should it be Simplified, or should it be Traditional? I suspect it's largely a matter of preference. A quick search of several popular websites revealed that in most cases, a request for base zh produces text which Google Translate recognizes as Simplified. In a few cases it did produce Traditional. But, I went with what the majority seemed to be doing.

Comment: Do you happen to know how these culture codes behave in a desktop app? I'm guessing that your web app receiving the base "zh" code is a "browser thing", so I'm hoping that a desktop app will always see the full "zh-XX" culture code? This means I only have one string resource (.resx) file to manage (zh-Hans), rather than have to include a "zh" resx file in my projects as well.